# Why subview of a UITableViewCell added incorrectly?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a problem.
I implemented a table view. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method  I increase cell's height and add a textview to that cell's `contentView`. But if I scroll table view down(for 10 cells for example) I will see the same textview again.
Can you please help me?

here's some code for better understanding the problem:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) 
    {
        return CELL_HEIGHT * 5;
    }
    return CELL_HEIGHT;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:TRUE];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row) 
    {
        selectedIndex = -1;
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:COOL_TAG] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    else
    {
        UITableViewCell *previousCell = [aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0]];

        if ([previousCell.contentView viewWithTag:COOL_TAG]) 
        {
            [[previousCell.contentView viewWithTag:COOL_TAG] removeFromSuperview];
        }
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        UITextView *text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 45, 255, 180)];
        [text.layer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        [text.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
        [text.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [text.layer setCornerRadius: 8.0f];
        [text.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [text setEditable:NO];
        text.text = [questionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        text.tag = COOL_TAG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:text];
    }

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: alloc cells in if(cell == nil){.....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the cells are being reused. So when you scroll down the cell where the textview is added is reused in another row.

I think the best way to solve this is to add the textview to the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Then you need to create an array in which you define if the row should show the textview or not. Then in the didselect method, change the array value and update the table.

Please note that the check should occur outside the if( cell == nil ) check in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, otherwise it wouldn't be called for reused cells.

Answer (score 0):

Create the textview in viewdidload  and add it to the tableview cell in CellForRow method.That might solve your problem

Comment: not sure. it just adds text view after table view initialization. I need to add it when user tap on cell..

Comment: ya just add the text view variable in DidselectRow method instead of cellForRow.It ll work fine.i just tested it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code because in your case cell is resused

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"YourCell";

```
YourCell *cell = (YourCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {

    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YourCell" owner:self options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
            cell =  (YourCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```